# Trigger not working with MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I Wrote this code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER testT BEFORE INSERT ON test3 
FOR EACH ROW 
IF NEW.a> NEW.b
THEN NEW.a=0
```

in mysql and table test3(a,b)

what i want is if user inserted a and b in test3 and a>b then a becomes 0 how should i write this?cause currently this code isnt working and im getting MySQL said:

> .#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '.a=0' at line 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not the valid syntax for a trigger, you forgot to use `SET`. Try this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER testT 
BEFORE INSERT ON test3 
FOR EACH ROW 
 IF NEW.a> NEW.b
  THEN SET NEW.a=0;
 END IF;
```

Comment: now it is giving this error :MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the `END IF` - have a look at my edited answer

Comment: A quick link to Mysql Documentation and example : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html to enforce your answer :)

Comment: Reading documentation is too simple, and if there is an obvious error, it's more helpful to point to it rather than telling "go, look that up yourself"